# Favourite Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>List</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ion-app>
        <ion-header>
            <ion-toolbar id="header" color="secondary">
                <ion-buttons slot="start">
                    <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
                </ion-buttons>
                <ion-title id="inbox">Places</ion-title>
                <ion-buttons slot="end">
                    <ion-button id="delete-all">
                        <ion-icon name="trash-outline"></ion-icon>
                    </ion-button>
                    <ion-button href="add.html">
                        <ion-icon name="add-outline"></ion-icon>
                        <ion-label>Add Place</ion-label>
                    </ion-button>
                </ion-buttons>
            </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>


        <ion-content>
            <ion-list id="place-list">

            </ion-list>
            <template id="place-template">
                <ion-item-sliding>
                    <ion-item lines="full">
                        <ion-label id="label" data="0">
                            <h2></h2>
                            <ion-icon size="large" id="ion-icon" slot="end"></ion-icon>
                        </ion-label>
                        <ion-buttons>
                            <ion-button id="star-button">
                                <ion-icon id="star" name="star-outline"></ion-icon>
                            </ion-button>
                        </ion-buttons>
                    </ion-item>
                    <ion-item-options side="end">
                        <ion-item-option>
                            <ion-buttons>
                                <ion-button id="delete_one" onclick="deleteOne()">
                                    <ion-icon size="large" name="trash-outline"></ion-icon>
                                </ion-button>
                            </ion-buttons>
                        </ion-item-option>
                    </ion-item-options>
                </ion-item-sliding>
            </template>
            
        </ion-content>

        <ion-menu side="start" menu-id="first" content-id="main">
            <ion-header>
                <ion-toolbar color="primary">
                    <ion-title>Start Menu</ion-title>
                </ion-toolbar>
            </ion-header>
            <ion-content>
                <ion-list>
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-buttons>
                            <ion-button href="index.html">
                                <ion-label>List of places</ion-label>
                                <ion-icon slot="end" name="list-outline"></ion-icon>
                            </ion-button>
                        </ion-buttons>
                    </ion-item>

                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-buttons>
                            <ion-button href="add.html">
                                <ion-label>Adding places</ion-label>
                                <ion-icon slot="end" name="add-outline"></ion-icon>
                            </ion-button>
                        </ion-buttons>
                    </ion-item>

                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-buttons>
                            <ion-button href="about.html">
                                <ion-label>About</ion-label>
                                <ion-icon slot="end" name="information-outline"></ion-icon>
                            </ion-button>
                        </ion-buttons>
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-menu>

        <div id="main"></div>
    </ion-app>
</body>
<script>

</script>
<script>
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    //Triggered when the user clicks on the trash icon when the user swipes on the ion-item
    function deleteOne() {
        showPlaces();
        var loadSaved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allPlaces"));
        console.log(localStorage);
        console.log(loadSaved);
        //Try to implement the same function but with a while loop to avoid
        //searching the remaining array position after the correct email has been found
        for (var i = 0; i < loadSaved.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            console.log(this);

            //remove one item at the position
            loadSaved.splice(i, 1);
        }
        if (loadSaved.length == 0) {
            localStorage.removeItem("allPlaces");
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem("allPlaces", JSON.stringify(loadSaved));
        }

        list.innerHTML = "";
        console.log(loadSaved);
    }


    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function confirmDeleteAlert() {
        //1. Create it
        var alert = document.createElement("ion-alert");
        //2. Set it
        alert.header = "Places";
        alert.message = "Are you sure you want to delete all Places?";
        alert.buttons = [
            {
                text: 'NO'
            },
            {
                text: 'YES',
                handler: () => {
                    deleteAll();
                    showPlaces();
                }
            }
        ]
        //3. Append it to the html
        document.body.appendChild(alert);
        //4. Display it
        return alert.present();
    }

    //When the page loads up, the function should run in the background so notes can be shown

    var list = document.getElementById("place-list");

    document.getElementById("delete-all").addEventListener("click", confirmDeleteAlert);

    // To delete all the notes and the key "allPlaces"
    function deleteAll() {
        localStorage.removeItem("allPlaces");
        showPlaces();
    }
</script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/script_pass_data.js"></script>
<script src="js/index2.js"></script>

</html>
```

All of the favourites are turning to true and false.

```
window.addEventListener("load", showPlaces);
var star = document.getElementById("star");
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
function showPlaces() {
    var template = document.getElementById("place-template");
    var loadSavedPlaces = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allPlaces"));
    // console.log(localStorage);
    var template = document.getElementById("place-template");
    // console.log(template);
    // if loadSavedPlaces is null then say "No places saved yet.", else make a copy of the template
    if (loadSavedPlaces == null) {
        list.innerHTML = "No places saved yet.";
        loadSavedPlaces.forEach(list);
        var label = document.getElementById("place-template");
        label.textContent = "No places saved yet";
        list.appendChild(label);
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i < loadSavedPlaces.length; i++) {
            // console.log(i);
            //We are copying what is inside the template. We are using firstElementChild so 
            //we do not copy the template tag - we just get ion-item
            var templateCOPY = template.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
            // console.log(templateCOPY);
            var label = templateCOPY.children[0].children[0];
            var starButton = templateCOPY.children[0].children[1];
            console.log(loadSavedPlaces[i]);
            starButton.addEventListener("click", favorite);
            label.addEventListener("click", openModal);
            // label.addEventListener("click", getPosition);
            label.children[0].textContent = loadSavedPlaces[i].address;
            label.children[1].name = loadSavedPlaces[i].placetype;
            // console.log(label);
            list.appendChild(templateCOPY);
        }
    }
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) { i = "0" + i };  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}

var today = new Date();
var loadSavedPlaces = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allPlaces"));
for (var i = 0; i < loadSavedPlaces.length; i++) {
    var places = [
        {
            'Address': loadSavedPlaces[i].address,
            'Description': loadSavedPlaces[i].description,
            'IconName': loadSavedPlaces[i].placetype,
            'DateAndTimeCreation': today.getFullYear() + '-' + checkTime((today.getMonth() + 1)) + '-' + checkTime(today.getDate()) + ' ' + checkTime(today.getHours()) + ':' + checkTime(today.getMinutes()),
        }
    ]
}
window.addEventListener("load", showPlaces);

function favorite() {
    // console.log(this.children[0].children[0]);
    var list = document.getElementById("place-list");
    
    var template = document.getElementById("place-template");
    var templateCOPY = template.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
    var label = templateCOPY.children[0].children[0];
    // var starButton = templateCOPY.children[0].children[1];
    var loadSavedPlaces = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allPlaces"));
    var x = document.querySelector("#star-button");
    var starButton = this.children[0];
    var icon = starButton.children[0];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < loadSavedPlaces.length; i++)
    {
        if(loadSavedPlaces[i].favorites == "false"){
            loadSavedPlaces[i].favorites = "true";
            icon.setAttribute("name", "star");
            icon.color = "warning";
        }
        else{
            loadSavedPlaces[i].favorites = "false";
            icon.setAttribute("name", "star-outline");
            icon.color = "dark";
        }
    }
    localStorage.setItem("allPlaces", JSON.stringify(loadSavedPlaces));
}

customElements.define('modal-page', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `
        <body>
        <ion-app>
            <ion-header>
                <ion-toolbar color="warning">
                    <ion-title>I am a modal</ion-title>
                    <ion-buttons slot="end">
                        <ion-button onclick="dismissModal()">
                            <ion-icon name="close-outline"></ion-icon>
                        </ion-button>
                    </ion-buttons>
                </ion-toolbar>
            </ion-header>

            <ion-content class="ion-padding">
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label">
                     <h2>Title: ${modalElement.componentProps.placeInfo.Address}</h2>
                      <h4>Description: ${modalElement.componentProps.placeInfo.Description}</h4>
                      Category: <ion-icon slot="end" name="${modalElement.componentProps.placeInfo.IconName}"></ion-icon><br>
                      Date and time created: <p>${modalElement.componentProps.placeInfo.DateAndTimeCreation}</p>
                      <div id="map">
                      <iframe id="google_map" width="425" height="350" frameboarder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>  
                      </div>
                    
                    </ion-label>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-app>
        </body>
        `;
    }
})

const modalElement = document.createElement("ion-modal");

function openModal() {
    modalElement.component = "modal-page";

    var c = function (pos) {
        var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
        var long = pos.coords.longitude;
        var cords = lat + ", " + long;
        document.getElementById("google_map").setAttribute("src", "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyCdrL38QxWO88FYNGgl1mq1lEXJBg4U6uA&q=" + cords);
        onDeviceReady();
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(c);
    modalElement.componentProps = {
        'placeInfo': places[this.getAttribute("data")]
    }
    document.body.appendChild(modalElement);
    return modalElement.present();
}
function dismissModal() {
    modalElement.dismiss();
}
```

We are copying what is inside the template. We are using firstElementChild so we do not copy the template tag - we just get ion-item.

I'm calling the function from the starButton in showPlaces().

By any chance, can only each of the favourites turn true and false when the star button is clicked?

Comment: Please add more details and your html and css to the question for a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the html but your "question" is still missing a question. I don't understand what is the goal and what is not working, if so...